# bundle install error in eventmachine installing

Tags: ruby

I had a problem trying to run the ruby project [OPEN-NDC-PROJECT](https://github.com/open-ndc/ndc-sandbox).

> bundle install

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 13.0.3
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Using i18n 1.5.1
Using minitest 5.14.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.9
Using activesupport 5.0.7.2
Using activemodel 5.0.7.2
Using arel 7.1.4
Using activerecord 5.0.7.2
Using awesome_print 1.8.0
Using descendants_tracker 0.0.4
Using ice_nine 0.11.2
Using axiom-types 0.1.1
Using dependor 1.0.1
Using bogus 0.1.6
Using builder 3.2.4
Using bundler 1.17.3
Using chronic 0.10.2
Using coderay 1.1.3
Using coercible 1.0.0
Using daemons 1.3.1
Using database_cleaner-core 2.0.1
Using database_cleaner-active_record 2.0.0
Using database_cleaner 2.0.1
Using diffy 3.4.0
Using equalizer 0.0.11
Fetching eventmachine 1.2.7
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -r
./siteconf20210217-76181-1jmnsjp.rb extconf.rb
--with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
checking for main() in -lcrypto... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for openssl/err.h... yes
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for pipe2() in unistd.h... no
checking for accept4() in sys/socket.h... no
checking for SOCK_CLOEXEC in sys/socket.h... no
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime()... no
checking for gethrtime()... no
CXXFLAGS=$(cxxflags) -Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated-declarations
-Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-unused-result -Wno-address
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling page.cpp
compiling pipe.cpp
compiling binder.cpp
compiling rubymain.cpp
compiling ssl.cpp
compiling ed.cpp
compiling cmain.cpp
compiling em.cpp
em.cpp:706:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_thread_select'; did you
mean 'rb_thread_fd_select'?
        if ((ret = rb_thread_select(kqfd + 1, &fdreads, NULL, NULL, &tv)) < 1) {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   rb_thread_fd_select
/Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:454:5:
note: 'rb_thread_fd_select' declared here
int rb_thread_fd_select(int, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, struct
timeval *);
    ^
em.cpp:706:40: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'rb_fdset_t *' with an
rvalue of type 'fd_set *'
        if ((ret = rb_thread_select(kqfd + 1, &fdreads, NULL, NULL, &tv)) < 1) {
                                              ^~~~~~~~
/Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:454:42:
note: passing argument to parameter here
int rb_thread_fd_select(int, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, struct
timeval *);
                                         ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [em.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/userName/RubymineProjects/ndc-sandbox/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7
for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/userName/RubymineProjects/ndc-sandbox/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.2.0-static/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  thin was resolved to 1.8.0, which depends on
    eventmachine
```

**gem_make.out**

```
/Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20210217-73483-4tmlc2.rb extconf.rb --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
checking for main() in -lcrypto... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for openssl/err.h... yes
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for pipe2() in unistd.h... no
checking for accept4() in sys/socket.h... no
checking for SOCK_CLOEXEC in sys/socket.h... no
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime()... no
checking for gethrtime()... no
CXXFLAGS=$(cxxflags) -Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-unused-result -Wno-address
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling page.cpp
compiling pipe.cpp
compiling binder.cpp
compiling rubymain.cpp
compiling ssl.cpp
compiling ed.cpp
compiling cmain.cpp
compiling em.cpp
em.cpp:706:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_thread_select'; did you mean 'rb_thread_fd_select'?
        if ((ret = rb_thread_select(kqfd + 1, &fdreads, NULL, NULL, &tv)) < 1) {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   rb_thread_fd_select
/Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:454:5: note: 'rb_thread_fd_select' declared here
int rb_thread_fd_select(int, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, struct timeval *);
    ^
em.cpp:706:40: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'rb_fdset_t *' with an rvalue of type 'fd_set *'
        if ((ret = rb_thread_select(kqfd + 1, &fdreads, NULL, NULL, &tv)) < 1) {
                                              ^~~~~~~~
/Users/userName/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:454:42: note: passing argument to parameter here
int rb_thread_fd_select(int, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, rb_fdset_t *, struct timeval *);
                                         ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [em.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.2'

gem 'json'                          # JSON
gem 'foreman'                       # Process management
gem 'racksh'
gem 'thin'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'rake'

# Formatting
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'htmlentities', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.4'

# DB
gem 'pg'
gem 'activerecord', '~> 5.0.0'      # Database
gem 'redis', '~>3.2'

# API Framework
gem 'grape'

group :development do
  gem 'rb-readline'
  gem 'rerun'
  gem 'mina' # Deployment
end

group :test do
  gem 'test-unit'
  gem "rack-test", require: "rack/test"
  gem 'test_xml'
  gem 'bogus'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'timecop'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'pry'
end
```

I tried the following ways to solve this problem.

> brew link openssql --force

```
    Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1
If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/userName/.bash_profile

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

**.base_profile**

```
#..
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"

export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

but result are the same

> gem install eventmachine -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include

> gem install eventmachine --pre

> bundle update eventmachine

> add "gem 'eventmachine', '=1.0.3'" at Gemfile

> change "gem 'eventmachine', '=1.0.4'" at Gemfile

> change "gem 'eventmachine', '~>1.0.4'" at Gemfile

How can I solve this problem?

I work for
Mac Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: Ruby 2.2.2 is really quite out of date, it's from April 2015 and isn't supported any longer. Can you use something like 2.7.2?

Comment: @tadman, This project is not a project that I made, so if I have to modify the code when I modify the version, I cannot to do. Is there any way to run Ruby 2.2.2?

Comment: The trouble here is that as you update your OS the compatibility with older versions of Ruby and various gems with C extensions, like `eventmachine` does tend to degrade. At some point you need to update Ruby and/or those dependencies to get a clean install. The alternative is fussing around and figuring out what the issue is, possibly forking and fixing these gems.

Comment: @tadman, I tried update ruby version to 2.7.2 and run command line bundle install is finished without error. If there is any change to the code when the version is updated, i need to modify it, but I think this is easier than modifying the Ruby 2.2.2 gem file. Thank you for your advice.